# Raspberry Pi vs ASUS Tinkerboard vs ??? for long term deployment. Is the MicroSD card the main point of failure?

Tags: sd-card, pi-4, pi-gpio

I'm currently working on a project that requires the Pi to be deployed for long periods (maybe years) without anybody physically being able to get at it.

So far the Pi has been perfect for development, but I'm worried about the MicroSD card failing within 1-2 years once it's deployed. I know you can extend the lifetime of an SD card by setting up the fs as read only, but how long will this extend the life of the device? Would it be reasonable to expect a MicroSD card with a read only fs to last 5+ years?

Would something like the ASUS tinkerboard be a better fit for this with it's inbuilt storage (I'm assuming that has a longer lifespan than an off the shelf MicroSD card)? Or are there any other SBCs or solutions that are made with this kind of lifespan in mind? Preferably ones compatible with Pi HATs.

Comment: If your worried about sd card failure, not that i've ever experienced it, why not use SSD connected to usb?

Comment: That is an option, however it adds significant cost to the build and the Pi4 doesnt allow direct boot from USB does it, so the SD Card would still be the failure point? I also don't need a huge amount of storage space, I just need what I do have to be reliable for potentially years of use.

Comment: Pi4 USB boot in beta https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=274595

Comment: Project Curacao Went six months between visits https://www.switchdoc.com/project-curacao-introduction-part-1/ but some Pis have run for years (see thread on RPT/RPF forum) without a problem.  Issue we have us we do not know your project and would be guessing unless we have something similar.  Can you create an accelerated wear test?  Even then can you state the card will be the sameor wear the same?